# Получение объекта через sender

Tags: c++, qt

Если я создаю сокет

```
QTcpSocket *_pSocket = new QTcpSocket(this);
connect( _pSocket, SIGNAL(readyRead()), this, SLOT(readTcpData()));
```

а потом используz его в коде

```
void readTcpData()
{
    QTcpSocket* _pSocket = (QTcpSocket*)sender();
    QByteArray recieved = _pSocket->readAll();
    emit readTCPdata_signal(recieved, _pSocket->peerAddress().toIPv4Address() );

    delete _pSocket;
}
```

удалится ли сокет который был создан первоначально?

Comment: Только когда произойдет удаление "this". QTcpSocket* _pSocket = (QTcpSocket*)sender() - сомнительное действие, т.к. вы не проверяете получилось ли приобразование в QTcpSocket. QByteArray recieved = _pSocket->readAll(); - при не верном сендере получите краш.

Comment: Есть вариант удалить немедленно? А если убрать родителя у сокета?

Comment: Почему сендер может оказаться оказаться не сокетом?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В Вашем примере, `_pSocket` в первом и втором случае - это один и тот же объект. Поэтому, в конце функции Вы удалите оба. И при следующем приходе сигнала на чтение будет UB (так как там висящий указатель).

FYI: Строка `QTcpSocket* _pSocket = (QTcpSocket*)sender();` не создает нового объекта и не увеличивает никаких счетчиков ссылок.

Comment: Согласен, если сокет 1.

Comment: этот сокет соединяется с сервером сервер дает ответ и закрывает коннект, и так в цикле я создаю сокет и удаляю (самом деле серверов много и мне так удобно их различать) таким образом мне нужно еще сигнал слот нужно разрывать?

Comment: если нужно  чистить - вызывайте deleteLater() Тогда Ваш сокет будет корректно освобожден. (в многих случаях, удаление QObject наследников напрямую может приводить к странным багам).

Comment: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#dtor.QObject - в документации написано, что не нужно (сигнал - слот).

Comment: Есть вариант удалить немедленно? А если убрать родителя у сокета?

Comment: С какой целью пытаетесь "удалять немедленно"? оптимизация? упираетесь в ресурсы, что то третье?

Comment: куча серверов с телеметрией, нахожу интерфейсф, беру айпи и маску, нахожу первый и количество,    `{
    QTcpSocket *_pSocket = new QTcpSocket();

        _pSocket->connectToHost(addr, port);
        if( _pSocket->waitForConnected(5) )
            if ( _pSocket->write( json_request ) )
            {
                connect( _pSocket, SIGNAL(readyRead()), this, SLOT(readTcpData()));

                return true;
            }

        delete _pSocket;
        return false;
    }`

Comment: куча это сотня-другая? тогда нет проблем. Более того, я бы переписал нормально на сигналы и избавился от waitForConnected

Comment: поясните пожалуйста как отказаться от вэйтконнекта?

Comment: Вообще данная конструкция работает, память вроде не течет, но есть проблема с завершением программы, падает. Объект с сокетами живет в другом треде.

Comment: ok, выясняется решается проблема XY.  Я писал. что приложение может вести себя странно - оно и падает. В целом тред тут даже и не нужен,  вместо waitForConnected используйте сигнал connected.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/75388/discussion-between-dow-jhob-and-kovadim).